# Convert MailApp.sendEmail code to GmailApp.sendEmail with HTML Body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All, I am looking for help from someone with more experience with this.  I have a cobbled together email script that works great as is. I want to specify the from: address using an alias and it's my understanding that I need to use GmailApp vs MailApp to accomplish this.  The trouble is, I can't figure out how to make my htmlBody work in the GmailApp version.

Here is my working MailApp code:

```
function SendPreReleaseAlertEmail(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('EmailSheet');
  var subject = sheet.getRange("M3").getValues();  // Change the subject as needed.
  var recipients = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();  // Change the recipient as needed.
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>" + "<P>"
   for (var x=6;x<14;x++) {                                       //Loop from * to * with a +1 increment
     message = message + sheet.getRange("M" + x).getValues() + "<BR>"      //Add row I(x) to the message 
   }
    message = message + "</HTML></BODY>"; 
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

And this is my FAILED attempt at converting it to GmailApp with a From address:

```
function SendPreReleaseAlertEmail(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('EmailSheet');
  var subject = sheet.getRange("M3").getValues();  // Change the subject as needed.
  var recipients = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();  // Change the recipient as needed.
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>" + "<P>"
   for (var x=6;x<14;x++) {                                       //Loop from * to * with a +1 increment
     message = message + sheet.getRange("M" + x).getValues() + "<BR>"      //Add row I(x) to the message 
   }
    message = message + "</HTML></BODY>"; 
   GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, {htmlBody: message}, {from: "moo@cow.com"});
}
```

The above code does in fact email from the alias.  But the htmlBody just has the words "[object Object]" in the body of the email.

It's Alive!  Here is the final code that solved my problem:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, '', {htmlBody: message, from: "moo@cow.com"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to fix two things.

1.The syntax is

```
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

So you may need to include a blank placeholder for `body` in your code.

2.You may also need to have both the `htmlBody` and `from` in the `options` JavaScript object like so:

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, '' , {
    htmlBody: message, 
    from: "moo@cow.com"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use MailApp like that:

```
var email = "exampleRec@email.com";
var Subject_to_Send = "This is an automated email";
  
var check_body = 
     "Good morning team,  <br/><br/>" 
     +"I hope this email finds you well. <br/><br/>";

MailApp.sendEmail( {to:email, subject:Subject_to_Send, body:check_body,htmlBody:check_body, from: "exampleSen@email.com"});
```

If you also want to send a **noReply** message you can adjust the last line as follows:

```
MailApp.sendEmail( {to:email, subject:Subject_to_Send, body:check_body,htmlBody:check_body, noReply: true});
```